# Set focus to next input field in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to focus the next input in a table field by pressing `enter`. 
The table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
            <td>Unit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
            <td>Unit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="group">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 3</td>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
            <td>Unit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="group">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 4</td>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
            <td>Unit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my JS to focus the next input field.

```
'change input[type="number"]': (event) => {
    $(event.target).closest('tr').next(':not(.group)').find('input').focus();
}
```

This is working for the first field. The next input field gets focused. But I can't focus the third input field.

I also tried

```
'change input[type="number"]': (event) => {
    $(event.target).closest('tr').siblings(':not(.group)').find('input').focus();
}
```

But then the focus is set to the last input field and I don't understand why.

Comment: Just missing in this post. sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery's `next()` only looks at the next sibling, not all following siblings. What you want is `nextAll()`:

```
$(event.target)
    .closest('tr')
    .nextAll('tr:not(.group)')
    .first()
    .find('input')
    .focus();
```

Comment: Because it will select both previous and subsequent siblings. You'll be `focus()`ing all of them, and so the last one will be the only one to get the focus. I used this codepen to solve the problem, and I left a comment that shows what happens with `.siblings()`: https://codepen.io/Yona-Appletree/pen/pNdGLV

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.